# Trouble with jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having difficulties getting a slider back button working correctly.
The slider simply fades out the first child and appends it to the end of its parent, nothing special.
It seems that when the back button is clicked it's not fading out, and the first child hangs until the cycle is complete, I'm not sure why. I'd appreciate some help with this one.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/853mtc1s/

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(slider_wrapper_id + ' :first').fadeOut('fast',function() {
        $(this).next('div.slide').fadeIn().end().appendTo(slider_wrapper_id);
    });

},4000);
$('.slider-control-forward').on('click', function(){
    $(slider_wrapper_id + ' :first').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).next('div.slide').fadeIn().end().appendTo(slider_wrapper_id);
    });
});
$('.slider-control-back').on('click', function(){
    $(slider_wrapper_id + ' :first').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).last('div.slide').fadeIn().end().appendTo(slider_wrapper_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your forward button works perfectly since it follows the same order for all the elements. But when you start going backwards, the order of the elements is messed up since you are appending them to odd positions. You'll need to completely redesign the way that your back button works unfortunately...

Comment: Will your slider always have 4 items?

Comment: I'd prefer it to but they're added dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not really sure why this one was so difficult to think about. In your forward function, you use jquery next() which selects the next sibling. However, in your backward function you select your element with $(this).last('div.slide'). Since $(this) has only one element in its collection, you are selecting itself. This is because the jquery last function does not select the last sibling but instead 'Selects the last matched element'. To get the element you want for the fadeIn, you have to select it with $(this).siblings().last(). The next mistake is calling end().appendTo(). This will get your elements out of order. You don't want end() because the element you want to move is the same one you just faded in (unlike the forward operation where the element you want to move is the previous sibling to the one you just faded in). So, to move the element you just faded in to the front of the queue, prepend it by not using end(). In your backward function, change:

```
$(this).last('div.slide').fadeIn().end().appendTo(slider_wrapper_id);
```

to:

```
$(this).siblings().last().fadeIn().prependTo(slider_wrapper_id);
```

and it will work as desired.